# Unable to assign values to entries in matrices

Tags: python, numpy, cmath

I'm trying to create a complex matrix and assign the 0,0 entry to the value of 1+0j. Here's the code I wrote:

```
import numpy as n
import cmath

M=n.zeros((5,5),dtype=complex)
M[0:0]=1+0j
print M
```

However, after executing, the 0,0 entry is still zero:

```
[[ 0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j]
 [ 0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j]
 [ 0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j]
 [ 0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j]
 [ 0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j]]
```

What's wrong with my code? What's the proper way to do it?

Comment: use `M[0,0]`, `M[0:0]` means view from row `0` to row `0` (exclusive) so basically empty view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to code your matrix element reference like this:

```
    M[0,0]=1+0j
```

The syntax M[0:0] would mean the first sublist to just before the first sublist, i.e. an empty element.  Try evaluating M[0:1]

```
    >>>> M[0:1]
    array([[ 1.+0.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j]])
```

Comment: For a two-dimensional numpy array, the element at row 0 and column 0 should be accessed using `M[0, 0]`.  In most cases, `M[0][0]` will work, but it is inefficient.